# How to say "See you soon" when meeting up with someone

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm just wondering a simple way to say "See you soon" when the context is that you are talking to your friend remotely (via phone/messaging) and you plan to meet up with them in the very near future (1 or 2 hours).

Would it be as simple as "Sugu ni miru"?

Thanks for your help,
Bazz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> a simple way to say "See you soon" when the context is that you are talking to your friend remotely (via phone/messaging) and **you plan to meet up with them in the very near future (1 or 2 hours)**.

In that situation I would say 「じゃ、あとで。」(← casual)

じゃ is the contracted pronunciation of では, literally "Then".

あとで。 as a greeting is a shortened way of saying あとで[会]{あ}いましょう, literally "Let's meet later" or "See you later".

If you want to sound more formal, you could say 「では、あとで。」 or even more formally 「では、のちほど。」

Comment: Thanks @Chocolate♦, what would the literal translation of that be?

Comment: @Bazz It's literally: "Then, later."

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say (mata or matane)

友達なら(また)か(またね)でいいと思います。

Comment: From the literal translation of "mata" meaning "again" I thought that it only applied to when you're saying "see you soon" in the context that you're parting with someone that you're going to meet again. Can you confirm that it also works when you're only meeting for the first time (casually)?

Comment: 1～2時間後にまた会うつもりの時に（「また後で」ではなく）「またね」という人は少ないと思います。